# Managing dependencies while working on a react-native library locally

Tags: react-native, npm, transpiler

I'm trying to develop a modification to an existing react native library (the library in question is [this one](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs), although hopefully the answer to my question will be generally applicable to any library development work.  I have an existing application that I would like to use with a modified version of this library.  I'm not quite sure how I can set this up so that the library can coexist with the app and both build processes run correctly when the library is modified.  I'm happy to run a command to update the app when the library changes, although I'd like to avoid that if possible.  In case it's relevant, I'm working on a Mac.

Things I've tried:

- Cloned the existing library into a parent directory of my app (so they're `project/myapp` and `project/react-navigation-tabs`)
- Then used `npm link ../react-navigation-tabs` from the app directory, which appeared to succesfully set up the link, but when I tried to test the app, the react native packaging server complained that importing "react" was an ambiguous reference (because both `project/myapp/node_modules/react` and `project/react-navigation-tabs/node_modules/react` existed)
- Removed the link produced in the last step and tried `npm install ../react-navigation-tabs` instead.  This again apparently succeeded, but then the react native packaging server complained that it 'couldn't find preset "react-native" relative to directory "project/react-navigation-tabs"'.  The preset in question is installed in the `project/myapp/node_modules` directory, but it seems that the packager expects it to be installed in both locations.

So:

- Is there any way of persuading `npm` to only install the necessary libraries in one location and share them?  Or alternatively install the development dependencies in both locations?
- Is there another way of organising the project that will allow me to perform the updates I need without needing to install dependencies in two separate locations?  This is complicated by the fact that the library in question will (presumably) need transpiling before it can be used.

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't change your `package.json` dependency to point to either the git repository or the local file path to the project you're modifying? I use the latter method when working on my own modules and it works fine. e.g., Make edits, rerun `yarn add <path_to_project>`, test changes in app.

Comment: @MichaelCheng - I thought that was what `npm install ../react-navigation-tabs` would do, but I'll certainly give it a try.

Comment: Perhaps try the absolute path? I tend to avoid npm on react native because of issues like npm v5 not working up until very recently, so I'm not familiar with what exactly `npm link` might have done.